# Permanently prune backups created by Time Machine

Tags: backup, time-machine, software-recommendation

I am cleaning up old Time Machine backups, which slows stuff down to a grind.  I want to tell Time Machine to delete all backups older than 3 months.  I'd also like for Time Machine to keep that as a default rather than having to do that by hand myself each time.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find this app, but I've never used it, I don't know if it works:
[Time Machine Editor](http://tclementdev.com/timemachineeditor/)

It purports to edit the frequency rules .plist for you.

Otherwise:
[image]

These are the rules. If you don't like them, use a different backup solution.

Comment: None of these options seems to be 'always delete backups older than X days' to avoid filling up the backup disks and having tmutil delete run in the background.

Comment: yeah... I didn't read down to the: "How does TimeMachineEditor preserve/discard backups?
TimeMachineEditor does not change that, it is handled by Time Machine. Time Machine will coalesce and discard backups as described in System Preferences > Time Machine." in the faq

Comment: a workaround might be to use the "when inactive" mode of operation in TimeMachineEditor so that it is running tmutil when you aren't around.

Comment: I really suspect I might have to write a bash script so that tmutil prunes out old backups in the background, hopefully speeding the whole exercise up.